# Tensorflow is not listing my dedicated GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, distributed-training

I have a dedicated GPU installed in my device. I want to use it for deep learning model training. I followed many tutorial related to setting up the tensorflow-gpu but no one worked for me.

[image: Check Image Here]

Please guide me and provide a proper step-by-step process to setup tensorflow-gpu with latest versions of all( tesnsorflow, cuda toolkit, cudnn , etc).

here are my GPU and CPU specification,

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10300H CPU @ 2.50GHz
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 GDDR6 @ 46B (128 bits)

I have tried many articles on medium and other platforms.
I have installed the versions of tf-gpu, cuda and cudnn according to official documentation but didn't work.

Comment: `tensorflow-gpu` has been removed for a while now. Did you follow the steps on enabling `gpu` capabilities in [`tensorflow`](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: Hi @Abhinav Singh, Please ensure that you are not installing `Tensorflow > 2.10` in Windows machine which is not supported for gpu. Please install `CUDA 11.2` and `cuDNN 8.1` which is compatible with `TF 2.5 - TF 2.10` as per this tested build config and try installing the Tensorflow again by verifying the Hardware/ Software requirements and step by step instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements). Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.